# How to make a queue of hashes in redis?

Tags: redis, queue

To make a queue in redis by using `LPUSH` and `LTRIM`, in python I do it like this:

```
if not str(key) in r.lrange('myq', 0 , -1):
    r.lpush("myq" , key)
    r.ltrim("myq" , 0, MYQ_LENGTH)
```

But how to store key:value pairs in a redis queue?

Suppose that `Keys` and `Values` can be **any** strings (so can not be splitted using `:`), what is the best way to push

```
Key1:Val1
Key2:Val2
Key3:Val3
Key4:Val4
```

into a queue 4 items, and when the 5th pair is pushed into the queue, it pop out `Key1:VAl1`?

Answer (score 3):

You can encode your strings using something like MessagePack or JSON, and push that into the list. Upon pop, perform the matching decode in the client (or write a Lua script that does it server-side).

Pseudo-code example:

```
r.lpush("myq", "{\"key1\":\"val1\"}")
...
ele = r.lpop("myq")
hash = JSON.decode(ele)
```

Comment: Depending on the size of your hashes it may be better to just give them an ID, and have the queue refer the the ID of the hash.

Comment: Yeah, but then you'd have to do another read and it is more expensive RAM-wise too... That design is ok and have its uses, but given the question it made more sense IMO to go the serialized way